# Two Same MSSql Query where one takes less Execution Time and Other takes So much Time to Execute But both id are different

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

[Our Trackomatic Database Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRV4P.png)
Two Same MSSql Queries where one takes less Execution Time and the other is takes so much time to Execute. Both id are different. I want to know why is this happening.

First query:

```
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 10 TrackerResponse.EventName,TrackerResponse.ReceiveTime,ISNull(TrackerResponse.InputStatus,0)  AS InputStatus,
                    TrackerResponse.Latitude,TrackerResponse.Longitude,TrackerResponse.Speed,
                    TrackerResponse.TrackerID,TrackerResponse.OdoMeter,TrackerResponse.Direction,
                    UserCar.CarNo FROM TrackerResponse
                    INNER JOIN UserCar ON (UserCar.TrackerID = TrackerResponse.TrackerID)
                    WHERE  (TrackerResponse.EventName IS NOT NULL AND TrackerResponse.EventName<>'')
                    AND TrackerResponse.TrackerID = 56 Order By ID DESC) AS Events)
```

Second Query:

```
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 10 TrackerResponse.EventName,TrackerResponse.ReceiveTime,ISNull(TrackerResponse.InputStatus,0)  AS InputStatus,
                    TrackerResponse.Latitude,TrackerResponse.Longitude,TrackerResponse.Speed,
                    TrackerResponse.TrackerID,TrackerResponse.OdoMeter,TrackerResponse.Direction,
                    UserCar.CarNo FROM TrackerResponse
                    INNER JOIN UserCar ON (UserCar.TrackerID = TrackerResponse.TrackerID)
                    WHERE  (TrackerResponse.EventName IS NOT NULL AND TrackerResponse.EventName<>'')
                    AND TrackerResponse.TrackerID = 112 Order By ID DESC) AS Events)
```

Some One Please Give the Perfect Solution for this Problem

Comment: my database is Sql Server 2012( Sql Management Studio i used) database

Comment: If the first query returns only the top 10 rows out of 100, it will run much faster from a query that returns the top 10 out of 100000. WIthout any *relevant* data, ie the number of queries returned *before* calling TOP, the total number of records, the existence of indexes or not and the execution plans, it's impossible to help

Answer (score 1):

One might be asking a lot more data then the other, you should provide way more information such as : the queries themselves and the data its trying to retrieve in both cases.

You wont get many answers here, if you don't use your spell check. Look at your sentences and you really have to clarify your question.

So 1. spellcheck, 2. look at sentences. 3. provide queries and example of data AND what type of database (oracle/MySQL).

Comment: - query's + queries :)